# How to divide an array of size (a,n,m) by an array of size (a,)?

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array, divide

I have two arrays: X of size (500, 10, 10) and Y with size (500,). I need to divide each (10x10) array in X by the corresponding element in Y.

```
for i in range(500):
    value[i] = X[i]/Y[i]
```

However, I get this error: `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.`

How can I do this division?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have `numpy` arrays: add additional axes to `Y` before division:

```
new_arr = X / Y[:, None, None]
```